# Unable to push new value to prevState array

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to set CheckoutArray with prevState.CheckoutArray + returnListArray everytime when page is mounted.
But state is not getting set.
Below is my code.

```
    this.state = {
      CheckoutArray: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let returnListArray = [];
    returnListArray.push(this.props.navigation.state.params.itemDetails);
    console.log('returnListArray', returnListArray);
    this.setState(
      prevState => (
        {
          CheckoutArray: [
            ...prevState.CheckoutArray,
            returnListArray,
          ],
        }
      ),
        () => console.log('CheckoutArray', this.state.CheckoutArray)
    );
  }
```

Comment: I think you should use the spread operator on returnListArray too so that the CheckoutArray would be an array instead of an array of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You are giving the callback to setState at the wrong place.

This order should work:

```js
this.setState(
  (prevState) => ({
    CheckoutArray: [...prevState.CheckoutArray, returnListArray],
  }),
  () => console.log('CheckoutArray', this.state.CheckoutArray),
);
```

also @Ramesh in comment is right, you probably want to concat both arrays:

```js
this.setState(
  (prevState) => ({
    CheckoutArray: prevState.CheckoutArray.concat(returnListArray),
  }),
  () => console.log('CheckoutArray', this.state.CheckoutArray),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with your syntax. This

```
 this.setState(
      prevState => (
        {
          CheckoutArray: [
            ...prevState.CheckoutArray,
            returnListArray,
          ],
        },
        () => console.log('CheckoutArray', this.state.CheckoutArray)
      ),
    );
```

Should be

```
 this.setState(
      prevState => (
        {
          CheckoutArray: [
            ...prevState.CheckoutArray,
            returnListArray,
          ],
        }
      ), () => console.log('CheckoutArray', this.state.CheckoutArray)

    );
```

The callback function which gets called when state is updated should be passed *as parameter to `setState`*, that is not what you were doing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want to append(push) my Checkout array with prevState.CheckoutArray + new value in returnList Array. Can you please help me ?As I am always getting only 1 item in CheckoutArray evertime.